# Invisible Circle mesh

Tags: visibility

I'm unable to see circle mesh.When I started using blender it was there but after a while it suddenly disappeared as it becomes invisible

Comment: hello please show a screenshot, maybe you need to unhide (Alt H) or press "/" to exit the local view?

Comment: If you're lookig at it "edge-on" and it's not selected you won't be able to see it. Try looking at it from another angle.